# How to fix XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, angular, cors

I have a problem in angular login component when I user NodeJS server REST API
to connect database (MongoDB)

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/users/login' from origin >'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the >'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is 'Content-Type' >which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The >credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by >the withCredentials attribute.

here is my code in nodejs file (app.js)

```
var cors = require ('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin:['http://localhost:4200','http://127.0.0.1:4200'],
    credentials:true
}));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://localhost:4200");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'Content-Type');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  next();
});
```

here is git log results :
https://prnt.sc/o38w12
In addition, register functions still works when I submit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[credentials](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html): Configures the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials CORS header. Set to true to pass the header, otherwise it is omitted. Not content-type

Can you try changing

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'Content-Type');
```

To

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

**

- Fixing the CORS Error

**
There are 2 ways to do so:-

1. if you own the backend server, it would be best to configure the
   backend server to return the appropriate CORS HTTP headers Configure
2. Angular CLI Proxy which is our focus in this article.

**

- Angular CLI proxy

**

Here, I am assuming you have an angular project with some services making HTTP requests.
Create the Proxy Configuration File called proxy.conf.json in the root of the src folder

```
                "/api": {
                    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
                    "secure": false
                }
            }
```

2. Configure angular.json with proxyConfig key under the architect>serve>options that point to the src/proxy.conf.json as below

> 

```
           "architect": {
                "serve": {
                  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                  "options": {
                    "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
                    "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
                  },
```

**

- Now, simply run ng serve and you are done.

**
FYI: You may also you this trick as a security measure to hide the server requests you making from being displayed in the browser.