# How to allow CORS in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have a React app (localhost:3000) and a Node app (localhost:3001) to run a simple system. **The problem is I'm getting the error** `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3001/app' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.`

I have tried with `app.use(cors())` and also with cors options as below. Still I'm getting the above error.

**Node app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    credentials: true,
    optionSuccessStatus: 200
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://localhost:3000");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    next();
});

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/app', (req, res) => {
    res.send({result: "hello"});
});

module.exports = app;
```

**React app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {

componentDidMount(){ this.runInstance(); }

runInstance = () => {
        axios.get(`localhost:3001/app`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log("res", res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("AXIOS ERROR:", err);
        })
    }

render() { return(<div></div>) }
}
export default App;
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56644035/how-to-fix-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy

Comment: @Andy I added those headers and updated my question as well. But still it gives the CORS error

Comment: @Amadan The Node server is running on 3001 port. And even with `app.use(cors())` the same error comes

Comment: Are you building your app with create-react-app?

Comment: @Andy Yes, with create-react-app

Comment: I'm surprised you need to navigate cors at all then. I've never had to. Try [adding proxy information to your package.json](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use nodejs

**installing cors**

```
npm install cors
```

After that

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Then after applying "cors" middleware. You need to insert "http://" before "localhost: in your react app".

**Example**

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/app`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log("res", res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("AXIOS ERROR:", err);
        })
```

Comment: i have update my answer @DavidJohns let me know if it working

Answer (score 0):

You are using a different port to the one defined in `corsOptions`, try like below.

```
// app.js

...
runInstance = () => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/app`)
    .then(res => {
        console.log("res", res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("AXIOS ERROR:", err);
    })
}
...
```

Update:

Change all references to 3000 to be 3001, so that your CORS configuration matches the request you are trying to make.

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3001/',
    credentials: true,
    optionSuccessStatus: 200
}
...

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://localhost:3001");
...
});
```

Comment: The Node server is running on 3001 port

Comment: All port references in the scenario you describe should be the same value, answer updated